# how i get height of a svg element using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am using d3.js to find the height of an `SVG` element with the following code

```
<script>
    var body = d3.select("body");
    console.log(body);
    var svg = body.select("svg");
    console.log(svg);
    console.log(svg.style("height"));
</script>

<svg class="svg" height="3300" width="2550">
   <image x="0" y="0" height="3300" width="2550" xlink:href="1.jpg"></image>
   <rect class="word" id="15" x="118" y="259" width="182" height="28"
      text="Substitute"></rect>
</svg>
```

but it returned an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null

Comment: Are you sure that your DOM items existed before you attempting to get them in JavaScript? This will work fine if the script was ran after the HTML items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load `js` after the `DOM` is redered. You can either put the `<script></script>` in the bottom of your `<body></body>` or have it inside the following `javascript` method.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
          //your code here
     });
```